# i want to get Notified when in any of android application open Softkeyboard for input in EditText?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-softkeyboard

Every One Expert Here is some of My Problem to how i can start this thing in my Application.

1. i want my to get notified in my android application through a `BroadCast` for open of softkeyboard in any of other android application for input text in that `EditText` of application. For Example my application is in background running Bluetooth Service Connected to other android mobile. Now i want to get known that that connected android mobile have open browser application and it get softkeyboard for input in browser `EditText` input.
2. Then i want to send key code from another android mobiles which is connect to that device via bluetooth and now i want to send input text in that `EditText` which open in first android mobile.

Let me known any one have better idea to do this thing.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question, could you try to rephrase that? As is, no disrespect meant, better english so we can try to answer.

Comment: @blindstuff Sorry for that you don't understand i will sure rephrase it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to write a custom soft keyboard, which you can find an example of here: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html

Then your bluetooth service will be able to talk to your custom keyboard directly to send keys to the waiting application.

Comment: but how i can make Continuous Connection between two android devices  how i can Use of Service in android have you Experience that before to make.And how i can send Key Stroke to Connected Other android Mobile like Bluetooth Chat  can send Char Sequence in android developer site.

Comment: @Herry: You will need to use two services. One for the keyboard (doing a custom keyboard requires writing a service) and a second one for the bt connection.

Comment: @Macarse In This Case You have right that i have to write two Service Class for Doing such type of Thing in android mobiles.Right Now i am getting problem with Make Constant Connection Using Bluetooth Chat Example which only Work for connect two device with there Class only .When we come out from any of it Screen Connection Lose.

Comment: @Herry you can send and receive broadcast using their package name u can simply put a braodcast reciver in ur application with intent filter of action_edit so whenever a edit text will call u will get notify even m not sure with action http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_EDIT better u see all the actions which will suit u well